# Sitemap Node URL not accepting Multiple querystring

Tags: .net, asp.net, sitemap

In the sitemap file, I have sitemap Node URL which have more than 1 query string, like...

```
<siteMapNode url="~/abc.aspx?m=2&c=2" title="title" description="" />
```

but I am getting error at '&'

how to handle multiple query string?

Comment: You may want to learn basic XML or use a Sitemap editor such as the one here: <http://blogs.ipona.com/davids/archive/2006/07/08/5516.aspx>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **&amp;** instead of **& - ampersand**.

Answer (score 2):

Use `&amp;` instead of `&`. As this is XML, ampersands are among the characters which need an [entity reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Comment: you should use & instead of &? not getting?